# x86 Assembly - $ not displaying correct address

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am using Visual Studio 2017, and wanted to test the $ symbol. Using the following code, I would expect the values of var1 and var2 to be different, but they are identical.

```
.data
var1 DWORD $
var3 BYTE 16 dup (0FFh)
var2 DWORD $
```

This is an image of what VS shows in memory

[image: what VS shows in memory]

The value for var1 makes sense to me, but if $ is supposed to display the next memory address, why is var2 displaying the same this as var1? Shouldn't it be displaying 004068A4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> .data
> var1 DWORD $
> var3 BYTE 16 dup (0FFh)
> var2 DWORD $
> ```

You won't see any difference because the special **$** compile-time symbol represents the current location in the **code** (.code) of the program.

Here you are using it in the .data section which has a separate address space.

Comment: In NASM, `section .data` / `var1 dd $` /... / `var2 dd $` *does* assemble to each dword containing its own address.  Yet another "interesting" difference between NASM and MASM.  (The NASM behaviour lets you do stuff like `msglen equ  $ - msg`.  In MASM, would you have to put a label at the end of the string and use `msg_end - msg`?)  I think the NASM behaviour is more useful and less surprising, unless there's a use-case I'm missing.

Comment: To my understanding, using the Equal-sign directive (=) works because the $ ends up getting placed in the .code segment instead of the .data segment. However, I do not understand how something like `ListSize = ($ - list)` would work, assuming list was just an identifier for an array of bytes. Wouldn't this be the same thing as subtracting the .code offset by some .data offset? Does the value of list in this case not refer to the first byte of my array?

Comment: Think of **$** as an overloaded operator. When used on its own, the assembler prefers to consider it as the location counter in the code section, but in an expression like `$ - list` the assembler knows to which section the *list* label belongs an thus is able to calculate the expected result which is a relative value anyway.

Comment: Consider `jmp $` where $ refers to a location in the code section, and then see `ListSize = ($ - list)` where $ refers to a location in the data section. When data and code share the same section it's easy. When they don't priorities have to be imposed.